# How to import a custom module in airflow dag?

Tags: python, import, airflow

I'm trying to import a custom module to my Airflow DAG.

Directory structure:

```
airflow/
├── dag
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_DAG.py
└── folder
    ├── __init__.py
    └── custom_module.py
```

my_DAG.py:

```
import logging
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from folder.custom_module import delete_inactives


def depurate():
    logging.info("Starting delete")
    delete_inactives()
    loggin.info("Depurate [OK]")


with DAG(dag_id='my_DAG',start_date=datetime(2022, 5, 28),schedule_interval=None) as dag:
    depurate_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='depurate_task',
        python_callable=depurate,
        dag=dag,
    )

depurate_task
```

Error:

> Broken DAG: [/home/hspecter/airflow/dags/my_DAG.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<frozenimportlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
> File "/home/hspecter/airflow/dags/my_DAG.py", line 4, in  from
> folder.custom_module import delete_inactives  ModuleNotFoundError: No
> module named 'folder'

Comment: Hi Gonzalo... Did you find any solution? I am facing similar issue. Here is my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73718754/getting-modulenotfounderror-even-though-i-already-have-init-py

Answer (score 1):

You can add the folder path to your pythonpath:

```bash
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/airflow
```