# Getting ModuleNotFoundError even though I already have __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am working on an Airflow-Python project. I have created a utils folder, and inside that I am creating a utility class to be used by different DAG's. I am not getting any error in my IDE(Pycharm), but on the Airflow DAG's UI getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`

Here is my project structure -

[image]
Inside my utils/**init**.py -

```
from .kairos_bq_to_mysql import BigQueryToMySql
```

Inside utils/kairos_bq_to_mysql.py -

It contains the actual class definition.

I am trying to import this class inside dags/bq_to_mysql/umc_cg_service_sync.py I am trying to import BigQueryToMySql class.

```
from utils import BigQueryToMySql
```

I don't get any error/warning in PyCharm. The class navigation also works fine. But on the Airflow UI Dashboard, I am getting error.

[image]

Can someone please help me fix this issue.

In my `docker-compose.yml`

```
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ./configs:/opt/airflow/configs
    - ./utils:/opt/airflow/utils
```

Do I need make any changes in my docker compose file ?

Comment: Have you tried adding an `__init__.py` in the `dags` directory?

Comment: @crunker99 Yes, tried adding __init__.py inside dags directory. Did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to import `utils` from the directory above the two packages, `utils` and `dags`.

`from kairos-aggs-airflow.utils import BigQueryToMySql`

However, that directory, `kairos-aggs-airflow` has hyphens and won't work. So either rename that directory or put the packages in a new directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))` this before your local import
like

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
from utils import BigQueryToMySql
```

This addes your dag python file into system variable worked for me

Comment: Not working for me :( Do I need to make any changes in my docker-compose file ?                    import os
import sys
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow import DAG
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
from utils import BigQueryToMySql

Comment: sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))) i think one more dirname will add utils in sys path single wont work here